# How to store objects which are common for another objects in Elastic Search?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have object of 'A' which have references to **rarely changed** object of 'RarelyChanged' (for example, user context) and frequently changed object of 'FrequentlyChanged'. "Rarely changed" means the many 'A' object will have reference to same 'RarelyChanged ' object. In another words 'RarelyChanged' objects are shared for 'A' objects.

```
public class A
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public RarelyChanged Rarely { get; set; }
   public FrequentlyChanged Frequently { get; set; }
}

public class RarelyChanged
{
   public string Login { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   // many others props
}

public class FrequentlyChanged
{
   public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to store data of 'RarelyChanged' for every 'A' object and I want to filter, sort whole document ('A') by 'RarelyChanged' props.

How to store 'RarelyChanged' objects in the right way in Elastic Search?

I know about parent/child relations and nested object. But is this for my case?
There is one interesting issue, in future realeases types in ES index will be removed.
Nested objects or child will be stored in **same type** (_doc) of single index or not?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, nested objects  will be stored in the same index. Childs must be in the same shard. For your question i would only make RarelyChanged nullable.  It will be easy to query them using .Exist in your application.

Comment: @LeBigCat, thanks for answer. RarelyChanged is mandatory field. but many objects have same value for this field and I want to separate this value and share among objects. This is "reusable child". Nested type is recommended for object list.

Comment: Ok, if you dont have to use (== query or retrieve) RarelyChanged data Parent / Child seems to be what you are looking for.  But if RarelyChanged field has many update (and break some parents childs relation) maybe duplicate the childs could be a good solution. As you write // many others props, i would avoid nested objects, except if you need to retrieve rarelyChanged data on query time.

Comment: As far as I know Parent / Child relationship is used when I need to update children frequently, but I won't update objects at all. For example, outer object is log entry and inner object is user context. Many entries have the same (common) user context and I don't see an appropriate objects relationship in Elastic for this case.

Comment: Yes, but it s seems in your data (i can be wrong) a child share between X parents could be update for only Y of them, so you would have to create a new child for the Y (could be a little tricky).

Comment: Is it mean I have duplicate a same child for different parents? Child might have only one parent